# Зачеркнуть неиспользуемое свойство в VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Когда-то в каком-то видео видел, как неиспользуемые переменные переменные были зачеркнуты, у меня же они просто темнее цвета, помогите найти, как мне изменить стилизацию (у них одинаковый scope).

На данный момент нашел только `editorUnnecessaryCode.border`, который задает цвет подчеркивающей линии (почему-то она не волнистая, а пунктирная).
А так же `editorUnnecessaryCode.opacity`, которое задает прозрачность текста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]